# How to serialize file upload field in Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to create form which contains file upload in Codeigniter. Here is my view:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('puzzles/create'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <input type="file" id="imgupload" name="puzzle" size="20" />
                    <?php echo form_error('puzzle'); ?><br />
                </div>
                <img id="imgpreview" src="#" alt="your image" />


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="health">Health</label>
                    <select name="health" class="form-control">
                        <option disabled selected value> -- select a health option -- </option>
                        <option value="new" <?php echo set_select('health','new', ( !empty($health) && $health == "new" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>New</option>
                        <option value="used" <?php echo set_select('health','used', ( !empty($health) && $health == "used" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Used</option>
                    </select>
                    <?php echo form_error('health'); ?><br />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer</label>
                    <select id="manufacturer" name="manufacturer" class="form-control">
                        <option disabled selected value> -- select an manufacturer -- </option>
                        <option value="manufacturer1" <?php echo set_select('manufacturer','manufacturer1', ( !empty($manufacturer) && $manufacturer == "manufacturer1" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?> >Manufacturer1</option>
                        <option value="manufacturer2" <?php echo set_select('manufacturer','manufacturer2', ( !empty($manufacturer) && $manufacturer == "manufacturer2" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?> >Manufacturer2</option>
                        <option value="manufacturer3" <?php echo set_select('manufacturer','manufacturer3', ( !empty($manufacturer) && $manufacturer == "manufacturer3" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?> >Manufacturer3</option>
                        <option value="manufacturer4" <?php echo set_select('manufacturer','manufacturer4', ( !empty($manufacturer) && $manufacturer == "manufacturer4" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?> >Manufacturer4</option>
                        <option value="other" <?php echo set_select('manufacturer','other', ( !empty($manufacturer) && $manufacturer == "other" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?> >Other</option>
                    </select>
                    <?php echo form_error('manufacturer'); ?><br />
                </div>

                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Puzzle item" class="btn  btn-primary btn-block" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I call the controller dynamically with ajax call

```
$('.myProfileDropdown li a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var actionUrl = $(this).attr('data-url');
        $.get(actionUrl, function(response){
            $('#profileInfoModal .modal-body').html(response);
            $('#profileInfoModal').modal();
        });
    });
```

so the form is inside the BS modal.
Next I use this JS to "catch" responses back to the same modal:

```
$('body').on('submit', '#profileInfoModal form', function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var formData = $(this).serialize(); 
        var actionUrl = $(this).attr('action');
        console.log(formData);
        $.post(actionUrl, formData, function(response){ 
            $('#profileInfoModal .modal-body').html(response);
        });
    });
```

However the file is not being uploaded. Form validation run but file upload returned `You did not select a file to upload.`. The problem is that post to actionUrl posts only health and manufacturer fields. I think that`s the problem.

Could someone explaine me how to add my  data to formData variable in JS?

UPDATE:

console.log returns `health=new&manufacturer=manufacturer1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: actionUrl, 
    type: "POST",             
    data: new FormData(document.forms.form),
    contentType: false,       
    cache: false,             
    processData:false, 
    success: function(data) {
        $("#response").html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FormData` here, you cant just upload a file in the way you are attempting.

Something like this (untested and from top of my head):

```
// Get the image input
var imgUpload = document.getElementById("imgupload");
var fileToUpload = imgUpload.files[0]; // I assume [0] is present

// Create a FormData
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("aFileName", fileToUpload, "theFilePath.jpg");
```

Then you'll be POSTing `formData`

Comment: No I get error that .append expects two arguments. However I will look into this method. But I dont understand where in your snippet I will get health and manufacturer fields?

Comment: Apologies, i missed the `name` param on `append()`.  You'll get the other fields from your form like you normally would.